# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in RefluxJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, refluxjs

Following the tutorials from this site: http://blog.krawaller.se/posts/the-reflux-data-flow-model/

I'm looking at replacing `var chatRef` to a dummy data instead of using `new Firebase(...)` as shown in the author example. Baffled how exactly this line read?

```
chatRef.on("value",this.updateChat.bind(this));
```

What is "value" and how `bind` work?

Tried to use var `chatRef = {0: "Hello", 1: "Hello"}` produce `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chatRef appears to be an event emitter with at least one custom function (push).

You could mock it like this:

```
// you'll need to include an event emitter library
var chatRef = new EventEmitter(); 
chatRef.push = function(data, cb){
  // if push emits a value event?  not sure if it does
  this.emit('value', {val: function(){ return data });
  cb(null);
}

// emit a fake message every second
setInterval(function(){
  chatRef.push({text: "hey", from: "me", to: "them"}, function(){})
}, 1000);
```

If you don't get it, you should read up on event emitters.

For the `.bind` call google `Function.prototoype.bind`.  In this case the bind just ensures that when the callback is called, it has the correct `this` value.

Comment: Just saw that it was a Firebase API as in chatRef.on likewise Firebase.on

Comment: What does the "value" do and is a type value or? In the code: this.emit('value',...). That the first time I seen other than "click" as in JQuery but this was Firebase API.

Comment: "value" is the name of the event.  The DOM has an event system, but there are others like the simple pubsub model in EventEmitter and Firebase.